# Как в Python Kivy задать задний фон?

Tags: python, kivy

Как в Kivy задать задний фон, я знаю что можно как-то добавить картинку в само окно, и поверх него наложить какой-нить лайаут допустим, но не знаю как,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1, 0, 0, 1)    # установка цвета нового фона
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте возможности библиотеки KivyMD - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
MDScreen:

    FitImage:
        source: 'cafe.jpg'

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "CLICK ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
FloatLayout:   #Общий
        id:fl1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'Fon.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #rows: 6
```